# Why I can't upgrade my kernel?

Tags: linux, debian, upgrade, kernel, raspberry-pi

I have perform the following command into ssh shell:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo reboot
```

But I still have an old kernel version, infact:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.10.25+ #622 PREEMPT Fri Jan 3 18:41:00 GMT 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Why my kernel is not updated? What am I missing? How can I solve?

Tnx

Answer (score 1):

Since you're upgrading your kernel and, at least if it were me, I'd be worried something could go terribly wrong, I'd recommend backing up your drive if possible (maybe using [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) or [`dd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)) *before* performing the upgrade.

In any case, there is a nice explanation [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-kernel-upgrade-howto/), which for you boils down to the following:

1. Find what kernel images are available by running

   `apt-cache search linux-image`
2. Then install the one which is subsequent to yours using

   `sudo apt-get install linux-image-x.x.x-xx`

   (where the 'x's are placeholders for the actual version numbers)
3. Finally, reboot the way you usually reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

If the output of the apt-get dist-upgrade was something like

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

You are likely on the latest available kernel through your package management tool. 
If you wanted to update to a new kernel, outside of your package management tool, you have to compile it. It is a bit tricky, and you have to use your existing kernel configuration, to preserve the currently available drivers and settings.